# Cloning a private GitHub repo, authenticated as a GitHub app

Tags: git, github

I'm building a CI application that does some work on the contents of a GitHub repo on a schedule, or every time new code is merged, via a Webhook.

I've created a GitHub app and got everything set up so users can sign in with it, grant it access to their repos, and configure their CI jobs.

I'm unable to find documentation on how to clone the full repo contents, if it is private, by authenticating as the user who connected my GitHub app. I found the [docs on getting the tree for a repo](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree) but it seems like I'd still have to go through that JSON response and download every file separately, which feels like re-implementing Git clone myself.

Right now I'm just launching the `git clone` command as a subprocess from my CI script. Just wondering what the solution is here. Should I use libgit2? Or use that tree API and download all the files?

Comment: There's a good answer for https.  Anyone know of an ssh option?

Comment: @jschmitter - look into Deploy Keys.  They're SSH keys, and they allow access to a single repo only, unlike personal access tokens, which give apps access to all of your repos.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Probably a little late to answer this, GitHub has an option to clone a repository through access tokens requested by the application.

[Github Documentation](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps/)

```
git clone https://x-access-token:<token>@github.com/owner/repo.git
```

Comment: It's never too late. This helps many, not just the original question asker.

Comment: does this still work?

Comment: It is still listed in the documentation https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps

Comment: You can do git operations with octokit - https://github.com/octokit/auth-token.js/#use-token-for-git-operations

Comment: I've found it also works if you replace `x-access-token` with `git`. Not sure if that's officially supported though. **Edit**: It seems that the username field doesn't matter here. It's just a placeholder to ensure that the token gets submitted as the password. Replacing `x-access-token` with `yolo` also works...

Comment: Here's the most direct link for where this is documented: https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/authenticating-as-a-github-app-installation#about-authentication-as-a-github-app-installation